# ClassLoader Propertites Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, filesystems

Use ClassLoader and Properties in Android Studio can not read the file, **an error**: **the input stream is empty**

Code:    `PullXml.getWheatherInfo(MainActivity.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/com/itheima/xmlpull/backup.xml"));`

Read.Properties file is the same error

But in Eclipse these are all right.  WHY??